# Why does Python 3.11 is slower than Python 2.7 in Google's App Engine Standard Environment?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, google-app-engine

We had an App Engine's standard environment application running in 2.7, and we upgraded it to 3.11.

Services/frameworks used by old app:

- Shared Memcache
- Task Queue
- Google's Discovery library (for Big Query)
- webapp2 Framework

Services/frameworks used by new app:

- Flask
- webapp2 was removed since it isn't compatible with Python 3.

We followed this Google's guide to upgrade our application and use the legacy bundled services: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/services/access#python-3

The codebase is simple. It reads a request and stores it in Big Query. It uses the Memcache service to throttle requests and the Task queue to call the "Store to Bigquery" endpoint in the same application.

After the upgrade we saw the following:

- Higher latency: from ~50ms to ~250ms
- Higher number of instances: from 6 to 30 using the same worklead
- Higher number of instance errors

[Previous instances performance (100% workload)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keZmm.png) vs
[Current instances performance (represents only the 20% of the total workload)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xY3c.png)

We tried to run the [Google's profiler](https://cloud.google.com/profiler/docs/profiling-python#standard-environment) but the platform couldn't install the package.

Is it normal to see this decrease in performance with this kind of upgrade?
<s>What could be the cause of this issues?</s>

We expect the same or better performance as the previous version.

**-- Update May, 2023 --**

We found in the Trace list that in the 2nd generation GAE environment (Python 3.11), the requests are passing through an HTTP load balancer before the AppServer component but in the 1st generation (Python 2.7), they go directly to the AppServer component. Then we conclude that the HTTP load balancer is causing the delay.

Why does the 2nd generation GAE environment need the HTTP load balancer?
Do I need to implement Google's external HTTP balancer?

Comment: You should check your code and try to only load python libraries at the point they're needed and not at the beginning of your file. You should also check your logs, look for entries where a new instance is created and then click to ```view trace details```. That will give you a breakdown of the different calls being made and how long each call took whenever a new instance of your App is loaded

Comment: Hi @NoCommandLine, I looked at the trace details for the requests managed by my two versions, and I found that the requests for the 2nd generation GAE environment (Python 3.11) are passing through a "HTTP load balancer" component but not in the 1st generation (Python 2.7). I noticed that the load balancer is causing the delay.

Comment: Documentation says all ```https``` requests for both Python 2 and 3 go through a load balancer (see [Python2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/reference/request-response-headers?skip_cache=true%22), [Python 3](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#https_and_forwarding_proxies). Can you double check that you've invoked the ```https``` endpoints of both your Python 2 & 3 versions of your App?